# How does ESP-MQTT get internet access?

Tags: arduino-esp32

I am using the ESP-MQTT functionality inside the arduino-esp32 framework. I am wondering how the class gets access to the internet. I open a WiFi connection, but that is completely separate with no return values. When initializing the MQTT Connection I also hand over no reference to the WiFi connection.

Here is my WiFi code:

```
#include <WiFi.h>

void connectWiFi()
{
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(WiFi.status());
  }
}
```

and here is my MQTT code:

```
#include <mqtt_client.h>

esp_mqtt_client_handle_t client = NULL;

void initializeMQTT()
{
    esp_mqtt_client_config_t mqtt_cfg = {
        .uri = "...",
        .client_id = "..."};
    client = esp_mqtt_client_init(&mqtt_cfg);
    esp_mqtt_client_register_event(client, MQTT_EVENT_ANY, mqtt_event_handler, client);
    esp_mqtt_client_start(client);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The library I know requires an obvious reference to the connection when initialising the MQTT class

```
WiFiClient wificlient;
MQTTClient mqttclient(&tasks, &wificlient, host, 1883, clientid, username, password);
```

But, the one you use can simply do something like #include <WiFi.h> object inside it's own code.
Wifi.h is globally accessible as it's WiFi.h file declares it's object instance as an **extern**

```
extern WiFiClass WiFi;
```

That would give that library (class) access to the WiFi object so it can use it internally without bothering you to send a reference to it.

Same is with "Serial", it's also globally accessible in any file that includes <Arduino.h> and so on ...

In case of an ESP, your library could be talking in a more direct way with the Espressif sdk, Arduino is a wrapper around it so is WiFi.h so it may not be that obvious. Have a look inside your library source files, you may find something like #include <esp_wifi.h> although following all references to figure out how it works could give you a headache

Hope this helps in some ways

p.s. Sometimes when I come across stuff like that I wonder if I should just start believing that inside my ESP lives a little unicorn that feeds on pixie dust an runs really fast making it all work?